# Prefixing logs with date in shell script

Tags: shell, date, echo

I have a shell script with a lot of echo statements. I want to prefix each line of output with the time/date.

So, I replaced every

```
echo "Some text1"
echo "Some text2"
```

with

```
echo "`date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`:: some text1"
echo "`date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`:: some text2"
```

This is rather ugly. Is there anyway to create an alias (or the analog to a #define in C), to make it cleaner.

Obviously, doing something like:

```
DATE=`date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`
echo "$DATE:: some text1"
echo "$DATE:: some text2"
```

... would not work, because in that case the DATE is only calculated once and each echo would have the same date.

I am thinking about replacing every echo with a print function call, that does the prefixing. I want to know if anyone has any other/better ideas.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echodate()
{
    echo `date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`:: $*
}

echodate Some text 1
echodate Some text 2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using bash...:

```
#!/bin/bash

function myecho() {
        echo "`date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`:: $@"
}

myecho "hola"
```

Comment: Better to use `$*` rather than `$@` inside of a larger string (since it's a context where `"$@"`'s behavior of splitting out to an arg-per-member is actively undesirable), and better to use the POSIX function declaration syntax absent a concrete reason to be incompatible with it.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo() {
    printf "`date`: $1\n"
}

echo "test"
```

--

will result in:

abi@cefix:~$ sh test.sh

Fr 18. Mär 13:33:35 CET 2011: test

so you dont have to change all your echo statements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, shell function or conversely use an alias:

```
alias now="date +%s" # or your specific date format
echo "`now` some text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just store the format:

```
format="+%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S::"
echo $(date $format) some text
```

Not so much quoting is needed, btw.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using KornShell (ksh) here is a function:

```
#** Description: Logs stringToLog to scriptLog using a standard date format.
#** Parameters:  ${1} stringToLog (Required)
#**              ${2} scriptLog (Required)
log() {
        echo "[`date +'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%s'`]: ${1}"  >> "${2}"
}
```

**Example of calling the above function:**

```
log "Starting foo script." "${PWD}/logs/foo.log"
```